# Could not load type 'AgencySystem' from assembly 'EPaymentInvoicing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been struggling with this for days now. googling and trying diff things but with no headway.

I'm doing an MVC project but i need to use services from another project(web project). I did build the web project and referenced its dll in the mvc project. I can access members from the referenced project and everything compiles just fine.

However, the trouble is at runtime at the point where my code is calling a class of the refereced project and its throwing this "could not load type" whatever!

This is the line of code that is problematic

```
 CurrentAgency = new AgencySystem().RetrieveByApiCode(agencyCode);
```

AgencySystem is in the referenced assembly.

but it keeps saying
    **"Could not load type 'EPaymentInvoicing.BusinessFacade.AgencySystem' from assembly 'EPaymentInvoicing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. "**

Any idea why?
NB: The referenced project was build with vs2008 and the MVC project is in vs2010

Thanks(if u need more info pls i'd be glad)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with the assembly names.
Thanks to Saibal i was able to see that both projects had the same assembly name and the runtime was probably refering to the referencing assembly and looking for the AgencySystem tyoe there.

Changing the name of one of the assembly fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the platform type. It may be that the dll was compiled for x64 and your project is set for x86 or vice versa.

Comment: @oliverdejohnson Go to project proeprty in VS and then select Build tab there you will see Target Platform.

Comment: Under your project properties, click on build and check for target platform. Change what is currently there and see if that works

Comment: i cant find target platform.i right clicked on d project and click on proeprty pages and then build tab. is this right?

Comment: @oliverdejohnson Right, There must be Target Platform field.

Comment: I can see it on the vs2010 project but not on the vs2008 one.the mvc one(vs2010) is pointing to ANY CPU. cant see Target Platform on the vs2008 project

Comment: @oliverdejohnson Any CPU is your target platform.

Comment: wait...i think i may have found the solution.in checking the properties i discovered both project have the same assembly name. I've actually renamed the mvc one to read EPaymentInvoicing.Web and ran again...this time its a more forgiving error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." let me try to fix this and see how it goes.if it works i'll let u know....and if it doesnt i'll still let u guys know.tnks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a platform problem as it should throw a BadImageFormatException in that case.

Does intellisense recognize the AgencySystem class? if that's true then probably you have referenced a newer assembly than the one that is copied in the compilation folder, so cleaning up the solution (and maybe deleting bin and obj folders) should fix it.

If intellisense is not recognizing the class then it probably doesn't exist.

I would recommend to add a version code and a strong name to the EPaymentInvoicing assembly specially if you are referencing it as a compiled assembly instead of a project.